# Wrong external screen resolution after wake up from sleep

Tags: display, kde, display-resolution, xrandr

After the Ubuntu distro upgrade (upgrade from LTS 20.04 to LTS 22.04, running KDE) I started experiencing a problem with external screen resolution after the wake up from sleep. The monitor resolution is small (1280x768) and doesn't respect the setting prior the sleep (1920x1200).

After the wake up from sleep:

```
> xrandr
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1280x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 535mm x 339mm
   1280x768      59.94* 
   # a list of lower resolutions
```

There is an error when trying to change the setting to the highest resolution supported by the monitor (which is not included in the above list).

```
> xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 1920x1200
xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1200
```

After the turn off and turn on of the external monitor, the resolution is somehow added to the xrandr list:

```
> xrandr
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1280x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 535mm x 339mm
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   # a list of resolutions
   1280x768      59.94* 
   # a list of lower resolutions
```

Now it is possible to change the resolution:

```
> xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 1920x1200
# no output, the resolution was successfully changed
```

After the change, the resolution is successfully changed and xrandr gives proper output:

```
> xrandr
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 535mm x 339mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   # a list of lower resolutions
```

The problem is not present on fresh start. However, it is consistently present after the wake up from sleep.

What can cause the problem and how may I fix it?

Running AMD based laptop (Ryzen 7 3700U with integrated graphics), the external monitor is connected via USB-C. There are no problems with laptop screen resolution, only external monitor is affected.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Gnome on 22.04, wrong resolution on wake when plugging in a USB-C monitor with integrated Intel graphics.  Have you tried reporting this as a bug yet?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this one as it still bothers me. I just reported the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1978980

Comment: This one together with another one (non working wifi hotspot) persuaded me to downgrade back to 20.04. However, this bug (wrong resolution) has been also applied on 20.04 in the meantime. Still no progress on ubuntu bugzila :-(

Comment: Unplugging and plugging the connector seems to fix the issue when it happens (ubuntu 22 lts).